# Netbeans debugger unable debug any project with a particular class name

Tags: java, netbeans

Some weird behavior in Netbeans 7.0.  Ostensibly something went wrong when I created a class, because now no matter what project I am in, if I create a class named "RainbowBall" in a package called "gamesandbox.agents" (even if I just created the package fresh), it compiles fine, but the debugger gives me "Thread main stopped" when I call the RainbowBall constructor.

Stripped down example from a freshly created project:

```
//RainbowTest.java
package rainbowtest;

import gamesandbox.agents.RainbowBall;

public class RainbowTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        RainbowBall r = new RainbowBall();
        System.out.println(r.toString());
    }
}

/*---------------*/
//RainbowBall.java
package gamesandbox.agents;

public class RainbowBall
{
 public RainbowBall() {};   
}
```

Again, this compiles fine, but the debugger acts like RainbowBall is an unresolvable symbol ("Thread Main Stopped at RainbowTest.java:10").

If I use *any* other class name (ex. "RainbowBall2") or *any* other package name I do not get this error.  It happens in freshly created projects as well as old ones, and even when no outside libraries/jars/packages are being used in any way.

I'll probably just change the name or try updating to the latest NetBeans, but it would be good to understand what's going on.  The IDE has clearly stored the name of the class somewhere permanent and project-agnostic, and is refusing to work with RainbowBalls like some kind of homophobe.

Comment: The output message you gave sounds like NetBeans thinks there is a breakpoint in the class. I'm not sure why it would be global to every project, though.

Comment: Aha, yes.  That's exactly the problem.  There was a breakpoint set for "Class RainbowBall load/unload," which apparently persists across projects just like breakpoints set for specific exceptions, etc.

Resolved.  I must have set that breakpoint by accident somehow.

Comment: Okay, I will post this as my answer then ;-)

Comment: Easy to do when trying to hit the little hint icons.

Comment: @trashgod, yeah, I think that's what happened.  I vaguely remember clicking something and being like "huh, wonder what I hit."

Comment: <laughs ruefully/> A lot of my mistakes get cached in `.netbeans/X.x/var/cache`. I've had to nuke it from orbit more than once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output message you gave sounds like NetBeans thinks there is a breakpoint in the class. I'm not sure why it would be global to every project, though.